# mongodb async issue NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, promise

I'm using mongodb for a while and had countered this same issue many times.. like so:

```
XCollection.find({})
.each(function (err, x) {
    if (err) throw err;

         branchCollection.findOne(
             {_id: new ObjectID(x.branchId)}
               , function(err, doc){
                       console.log(x.branchId);
               });
.....
```

and I see sometimes that findOne not working very well, x document changes because of the upper each, and that's affecting my code! I recognize that the problem is because those requests (db requests) is async. but what the recommended method to deal with this issue?

Thanks,
Best Regards

Comment: This is very vague and unclear: `findOne not working very well`.  What isn't happening that you want to happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: Unmolested, `x` can be reliably used in the inner function as it is trapped in a closure formed by the outer function. It seems likely that your analysis is incorrect and something else is causing your "not working very well". For example, is `x` messed with in the `.....` code?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use new ObjectID to query the ID field. A string will suffice.

```
  branchCollection.findOne(
         {_id: x.branchId}
           , function(err, doc){
                   console.log(doc._id);
           });
```

On another note, you should not be using the x variable in your async call. You should use:

```
console.log(doc._id)
```

Other than that, I'm not sure I understand what your question is?  Are you receiving an error?

Comment: I printed x.branchId to say that I'm not moving on all the records. what's happening is that the respone x.branchId logging after some loops.

Comment: The variable x is constantly changing as you are in the .each() loop. The findOne callback will happen well after the loop finishes processing. Referencing x like this will cause very odd behavior

Comment: so what to do in this case?